# Android ListView modifies after onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with ListView. the thing is that when I click on any item from list, all elements are changing their positions. I've made ListViewAdapter that extends BaseAdapter and in getView I take data from public static ArrayList of items which is populated by AsyncTask with ProgressBar (which is called at the end of onCreate() ). The ListView takes new adapter only once. I have made neither notifyDataSetChanged() method on adapter nor any kind of invalidate(). ArrayList of items isn't changed from code anywhere. Thanks to debugger I know that items are relocating after finishing onItemClick() method (which has only three lines: declare new Intent, put extras and startActivity() ) from ListView, but before first line from the new Activity's onCreate(). I don't know where to search for the reason of that issue. Any suggestions? What kind of source code will help here?

Here's getView():

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             ViewHolder holder;
             if (convertView == null) {
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.trophies_listitem, null);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();

                 holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListItemName);
                 holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListItemSpecies);
                 holder.text3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListItemWeigth);
                 holder.text4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListItemJagdrevier);
                 holder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListItemPhoto);
                 holder.label1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TrophiesListLabel1);
                 convertView.setTag(holder);
             } 
             else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                 return convertView;
             }

             DownloadedTrophy t = (DownloadedTrophy) trophies.get(position);
             holder.text.setText(t.getTrophy_title());
             if(t.getTrophy_species()!=null && t.getTrophy_species().length()>0 && Integer.parseInt(t.getTrophy_species())>0) 
                 holder.text2.setText(Main.mSpecies.getItemByKeyValue("id", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(t.getTrophy_species()) - 1)).get("name"));       
             holder.text3.setText(t.getTrophy_weight());
             holder.text4.setText(t.getTrophy_place());

             byte [] picture = t.getPictureSmall();
             if(picture!=null){
                 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picture, 0, picture.length);
                 holder.photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                } else {
                    Bitmap bm;
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.trophy_none);
                    holder.photo.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }

             holder.label1.setText("Ort:");

             return convertView;
          }
```

Comment: Your overridden getView method would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing View's for different elements (a good thing) but your ViewHolder object's reference will still hold references to the previous elements objects. It would be better (and work) to re-find them.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-find them" ? For every getView() making convertView.findViewById() ?

Comment: Yes, don't use a ViewHolder and call convertView.findX each time. Or, use a dictionary keyed on an element ID with a value of the ViewHolder, etc.

Comment: I've found exact reason: "return convertView" from else statement. Now I just have to remove downloading picture from that code :-) Thanks a lot!